# How add css and html in vue js Like an angular css ,html and typescript in separate file

Tags: html, css, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

**How i add css and html separately in vue js**

i am beginner in vue and learn vue js but few question in my mind how can i add separately css and html file like an angular thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a single file component like :

```
<template>
  <div>This will be pre-compiled</div>
</template>
<script src="./my-component.js"></script>
<style src="./my-component.css"></style>
```

Comment: you means i  create three separated file  eg component.js , component.css and component.HTML and import  component.js , component.css path in  component.HTML

Comment: three files, `component.vue` which contains the code above and the .js and .css files

Comment: also, you can write your css code directly in component, inside <style></style>. Moreover, it allows to separate your styles for particular components using attribute scope for <style>